# X axis title is disappearing after first time, when reloading rGrpah chart on same div

Tags: rgraph

I am using rGraph to draw the chart. it is working fine for the first time. when trying to generate the graph with different input data for the second time, without refreshing the page. The graph is generating fine, but the x-axis title is disappearing. can anyone help me with this?

FYI: I am making that div empty, before generating the graph.

Attaching image:
1: [image]

In the first image, you can see the Date.

2. [image]

Here you don't see the Date. when I change the input data and tried to generate the chart.

```
            if(document.getElementById(chartID)){
                RG.ObjectRegistry.Remove(document.getElementById(chartID));
            }
            var barGraph = new RGraph.Bar({
                id: chartID,
                data: chartData,
                options: {
                    variant: '3d',
                    variantThreedAngle: 0.05,
                    colorsStroke: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                    colors: chartColorArr,
                    marginTop: 35,
                    marginLeft: 45,
                    marginRight: 15,
                    marginBottom: 85,
                    xaxisLabels: x_axis_label_Arr,
                    shadowColor:'#ccc',
                    shadowOffsetx: 3,
                    backgroundGridColor: '#eee',
                    xaxisScaleZerostart: true,
                    axesColor: '#f2f2f2',
                    //yaxisScaleUnitsPost: 'H',
                    //title: 'User Sessions',
                    //key: [legendsTitle],
                    keyShadow: true,
                    keyShadowColor: '#ccc',
                    keyShadowOffsety: 0,
                    keyShadowOffsetx: 3,
                    keyShadowBlur: 15,
                    variantThreedXaxis : true,
                    variantThreedYaxis : true,
                    bevelled : false,
                    axes : true,
                    tooltips: chartTooltipArr,
                    tooltipsEvent : 'onmousemove',
                     xaxisTitle : **'Date',**
                    yaxisTitle : yAxisTitle,
                    xaxisTitleSize : legendFontSize,
                    yaxisTitleSize : legendFontSize,
                    xaxisLabelsSize : legendFontSize,
                    yaxisLabelsSize : legendFontSize,
                    yaxisTitlePos : 0.1,
                    colorsSequential : true,

                }
            });
            barGraph.draw();

Thanks
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the looks of the 3D style and some other cues, you're using quite an old version. Here's two modern-style 3D charts:

https://www.rgraph.net/demos/bar-3d-effect-multi-row.html

https://www.rgraph.net/demos/bar-ajax.html

There's more examples in the download archive which are worth looking at.

As for the problem with your chart, I think the easiest solution would be to set the textAccessible option to false:

```
textAccessible: false,
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It is working now. 
One more question Richard. Is there any option to make graph non-tilt?

Comment: No problem. What do you mean by "non-tilt"? Do you mean change the new 3D style to the old?

Comment: Hi Richard, After adding  extAccessible: false, option, Chart is getting tilt . I want graph horizontally, as you are seeing in the above attached screenshots.

Comment: You could try setting the variantThreedAngle property to 0 - I have vague memories of adding this to control the angle.